# Adding SQL Server 2008 R2 to domain

Tags: active-directory, sql-server

I am attempting to add a machine running SQL Server 2008 R2 to a domain.  When it was a standalone machine I could access SQL Server, but once I joined the domain I get:
"Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections."
I set up an MSA and am running all of the SQL Server services under it.  I can access it from the same machine, but not from any other machine.
I am an accidental sysadmin, so I'm struggling to figure things out.  I'm a developer and the person who set up the network is long gone, so somehow I'm the logical choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After joining a domain, current firewall profile switches to "Domain Networks". Either alter its settings to allow the traffic you want or just disable it.

Comment: Thanks.  When the machine was standalone, the firewall was disabled, but apparently when I joined it to the domain, it enabled it.